# how does objIE.Document.body.innertext work?

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to understand how the `objIE.Document.body.innertext` works. From what I've read, it's almost like `CTRL+C`, however, I'm trying to get it to work and something's missing. Here's the code:

```
Dim objIE
Dim strPrintText

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objIE.Navigate "www.bing.com"
strPrintText = objIE.Document.body.innertext

msgbox(strPrintText)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wait until the browser is ready (and not use param list () when calling a Sub):

```
Dim objIE
Dim strPrintText

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objIE.Navigate "www.bing.com"

Do Until objIE.readyState = 4 : Wscript.Sleep 10 : Loop

strPrintText = objIE.Document.body.innertext

msgbox strPrintText
```

Please cf [this for background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10071209/603855).

**WRT param list () in Sub calls:**

```
>> MsgBox "No param () when calling a Sub!", vbOkOnly
>>
>> MsgBox("No param () when calling a Sub!", vbOkOnly)
>>
Error Number:       1044
Error Description:  Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub
>>
>> MsgBox "Do you believe me now?", vbOkOnly
```

For theory/reason cf [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx); and reflect on the merit of "it works" when discussing rules of programming (or ethics: stealing works fine, as long you are not caught).

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. I still have `()` around my variable in the message box and it works. This is just what I needed.

Comment: I guess I'm lost on the "cf"...are you saying just because it works, doesn't mean you do it? I can remove the `()` and it works the same, but if it's preferable that I don't use them when creating a message box, I can adapt to that. Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: I read the blog you attached. Now it makes sense. Thanks for all the helpful info.