# InternetExplorer COM document available in PowerShell ISE but not in regular PS console

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, com, scripting

The code below works in PowerShell ISE but when ran in regular PowerShell console, the document object is empty:

```
$ie = New-Object -COM InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate('http://www.example.com')
$ie.Visible = $true
do { Start-Sleep -m 100 } while ( $ie.busy )

$document = $ie.document
$window = $document.parentWindow

"Ready state: " + $ie.ReadyState
"Document: " + $document
"Window: " + $window
```

Output in PowerShell ISE:

```
Ready state: 4
Document: mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
Window: System.__ComObject
```

Output in regular PowerShell console:

```
Ready state: 4
Document: mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
Window:
```

When ran in PowerShell.exe, the `$window` and all other properties of `$document` are null. Why is that and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try execute your regular console with `-sta` option.

Comment: It appears that PowerShell's MTA\STA defaults changed between PowerShell v2.0 and v3.0.

Comment: I find it really hard to believe this is the reason, as `InternetExplorer.Application` is an out-of-proc COM object.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [`ReadyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752141(v=vs.85).aspx) property for completion, instead of the flacky [`Busy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752113(v=vs.85).aspx) property, which may oscilate and serves mostly the purpose of telling if the Stop button should be available:

```
do { Start-Sleep -m 100 } while ( $ie.ReadyState -ne 4 )
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't resolve this particular problem. Running PowerShell with -STA switch seems to be working.

Comment: Good advice on use of ReadyState BTW, I found more info on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10071209/450913).