# Excel VBA loop to input data in webpage

Tags: vba, excel, loops, html

I have gone through many articles and able to input data in to webpage from excel. Now I am trying to use a loop because I have to entry data for 10 to 50 times in the same page.

Here is the code

```
Sub vfcp()

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Top = 100
objIE.Left = 100
objIE.Width = 800
objIE.Height = 800
objIE.AddressBar = 1
objIE.StatusBar = 1
objIE.Toolbar = 1
objIE.Visible = True

Dim Input

Range("A2").Select

objIE.Navigate ("https://www.askebsa.dol.gov/VFCPCalculator/WebCalculator.aspx")

Do Until Selection.Offset(0, 0).Value = ""

  If objIE.ReadyState = 4 Then
  Input = Selection.Offset(0, 2).Value

  objIE.document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_txtPrincipal").Value = Input

  objIE.document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_cmdCalculate").Click

  Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

  End If

Loop
End Sub
```

The problems in this code is, I have a list of 10 date. the loop inputs the last date of the list. I am trying to input the first date and click submit, then wait for the page to load and input the second date, and stop the loop if there is an empty cell.

Comment: Try doevents or application.wait(estimate time taken). You would also need to retrieve the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the code to enter the dates? You cannot click without them.

> "then wait for the page to load and input the second date"

you can achieve this by inserting the following between your End If and Loop lines.

```
    'Allows IE to load
    While objIE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the idea. I actually didn't show here date input in order to shorten the code. I used only input variable to show it. BTW, I tried adding your code but no luck.

Comment: Could you post the entire code, and some test data?

Comment: Hey bro, the following code worked.

`While objIE.Busy
        DoEvents
Wend`

I know this and your code is same but dont know why it did not worked

Comment: Perfect! I used to generally use that instead of ReadyState. However, it seems like this sometimes doesn't work. They are practically the same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071048/internet-explorer-automation-busy-v-s-readystate-property

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too hard.  I went to that URL, hit F12 to see the code behind the site, and started searching for the appropriate ID names ('Principal:', 'Loss Date:', etc).  That's about it.  Run the script to see a working version.  Oh, yeah, set a reference to 'Microsoft Internet Controls' before you run the code.

```
Sub TryThis()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "https://www.askebsa.dol.gov/VFCPCalculator/WebCalculator.aspx"

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readystate = 4
'ie READYSTATE has 5 different status codes, here we are using status 4:

Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_txtPrincipal").SetAttribute("value", "100000")
Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_txtLossDateMonth").SetAttribute("value", "01")
Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_txtLossDateDay").SetAttribute("value", "01")
Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_txtLossDateYear").SetAttribute("value", "2016")

Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_txtRecoveryDateMonth").SetAttribute("value", "01")
Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_txtRecoveryDateDay").SetAttribute("value", "01")
Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_txtRecoveryDateYear").SetAttribute("value", "2017")

Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_txtFinalPaymentMonth").SetAttribute("value", "12")
Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_txtFinalPaymentDay").SetAttribute("value", "30")
Call ie.Document.GetElementByID("_ctl0_MainContent_txtFinalPaymentYear").SetAttribute("value", "2017")

'to find the "<input……/>" tag hyper link and to click the button
Set AllInputs = ie.Document.getelementsbytagname("input") 'you can use any tagname as you wish
    For Each hyper_link In AllInputs
        If hyper_link.Name = "_ctl0:MainContent:cmdCalculate" Then 'you can use .name, .id etc
            hyper_link.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Do

DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readystate = 3
Do

DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readystate = 4


End Sub
```

If you want to scrape the results, refresh the URL and do the same as I described above: F12, search for the relevant IDs and/or names, and pull those into a Worksheet in Excel.  I'll leave it to you to figure out that part.  It will be a good learning experience!!!

Comment: Thank you for the response bro, this while loop in my code solved the priblem 

`While objIE.Busy 
DoEvents 
Wend`